# Ruby Yaml - Create instance Variables Directly from a YML file

Tags: ruby, yaml

Hi I want to create A YML file and load them as instance variables instead. How can I do that.

Comment: Hi  @mu is too short,  Can you post links to any other ways ? I am especially trying to solve this - I can load as string values, not as hash objects or like arrays etc. Its erroring out `can't convert Hash into String (TypeError)`.
Why is it too broad or too many possible answers.  My answer is quite short

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yml_File.yml` File ::

```
default:
    browserversion:  43
dev:
    browser_02:  iexplore
qa_01:
    browser_default:  chrome
qa_02:
    browser_default:  safari
```

Check the below Code::

```
p yml_File = YAML.load_file(File.dirname(__FILE__).gsub('/', '\\') + '\\Profiles.yml')    
yml_File.each_key {|key_Value|    
  va = yml_File[key_Value].to_s
  var_name = "@#{key_Value}"  # the '@' is required
  self.instance_variable_set(var_name, va)
  p "Name of Instance variable '#{key_Value}'  is :: " + var_name.to_s + ' - And Key value is : ' +   eval("@#{key_Value}")    
}

p @dev
p @qa_01
p @qa_02
```

Note - Ruby 1.9+ atleast

Comment: Thanks  a lot - that was nice